# missing parameter type for expanded function - what does it depend on?

Tags: scala, types

```
class A {
  def a(): Unit = ()
  def b[T](f: A => T): T = f(new A())
  def c(): Unit = b { _.a() }
  def d(): Boolean = b { w => w.a(); true }
//def e(): Boolean = b { _.a(); true } // does not compile - why not, if c compiles?
}
```

In the e() method of the above class, I thought the compiler would be able to infer the type of "_" as it does in c(). However, with scala 2.11.7, e() results in a "missing parameter type for expanded function. Why? Is it something the compiler ought to be able to (=compiler bug) or is the compiler correct in complaining?

Comment: Short answer: because 'e' does not give a clue about what the expression "_.a()" returns. In the 'c' method, you have clearly defined that the return type of the expression should be Unit, so the compiler has more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because `b { _.a(); true }` get's translated by compiler into `b { w => { w.a() }; true }`, instead of intended `b { w => { w.a(); true } }`. So it computes the whole expression and tries to pass the expression of type `Boolean` to `b` instead of `A => Boolean`. At least that's the only explanation I see, unfortunately I do not know how to check that. Compiler's error seems to be quite honest in trying to say this.

Overall you should not use `_` wildcard with complex expressions. They are designed only for simple ones

I also think @Felix comment to your question is correct as well - partially it is the problem also. Compiler has ambiguity: `T` can be `Unit` or `Boolean`, and it just solves it incorrectly. Unfortunately it doesn't help even if you define `b` to accept `A => Boolean`

P.S. By the proper compiler message I meant this one:

```
Error:(24, 36) type mismatch;
 found   : Boolean(true)
 required: Main.A => Boolean
    def e(): Boolean = bb { _.a(); true } // does not compile - why not, if c compiles?
                               ^
```

Comment: I just noted that `def c(): Unit = b { _.a() ; Unit }` doesn't compile either, with the same error message.

Comment: It still the same as with `Boolean`. `A => Unit` and `Unit` are different types

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't think it's a bug of scala compiler.

for the function `d()`, it should be expanded as:

```
def d(): Boolean = b { w => {w.a(); true} }
```

not

```
def d(): Boolean = b { {w => w.a()}; true }
```

so maybe it will cause some ambiguities.

for the function `e()`, because compiler don't know what's specified type of wildcard `_`.

The example:

```
scala> def f(s: String): String = s
f: (s: String)String

scala> List("foo", "bar").map(f(_.toUpperCase))
<console>:12: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.toUpperCase)

scala> List("foo", "bar").map(i => f(i.toUpperCase))
res3: List[String] = List(FOO, BAR)
```

because for anoymous function, the compiler can't infer what's type of wildcard `_`.

```
def e(): Boolean = b { _.a(); true }
```

the compiler don't know what's the type of `_` in the above code.

because it can be translated as:

```
def e(): Boolean = b {{_.a()}; true }
```

or:

```
def e(): Boolean = b {{x => x.a()}; true }
```

Comment: Even if you try `b { (_: A).a(); true }` it still does not work, so the problem is not with the type inference. The same thing about your example with the list. Also I think `def d(): Boolean = b { w => w.a(); true }` is correctly translated into `def d(): Boolean = b { w => {w.a(); true } }`, did not understand whether you meant this is not like that, or not. I think for some reason compiler translates the expression into wrong `b { w => { w.a()}; true }`, probably because wildcards were not designed to maintain complex expressions, please see my answer

Comment: `def e(): Boolean = b { _.a(); true }` the compiler will throw `<console>:16: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => x$2.a())
         def e(): Boolean = b {_.a(); true }`, it means that compiler can not infer the type of `_`. my updates has explained why it can't infer, because it has ambiguities to infer. the correct usage should be: `def d(): Boolean = b { w => w.a(); true }`

Comment: This error is misleading. Actually my compiler throws two errors, and the second one is correct (I've posted it in my answer). This one is thrown because after translation of `b { _.a(); true }` into `b { w => { w.a(); } true }` type of `w` is unknown. But the original error is not because compiler cannot infer type, but because the type of `{ w => { w.a(); }; true } ` is `Boolean` instead of `A => Boolean`, and that's the reason why it do not infer type

Comment: ok, I think `def e(): Boolean = b { _.a(); true }` should equal to ` def e(): Boolean = b {_ => _.a(); true }` like: `def d(): Boolean = b { w => w.a(); true }` base on the throwed two errors.

Comment: I'd agree, I also expected for them to be the same, but actually they are not. `def d(): Boolean = b { w => w.a(); true }` compiles correctly. I guess compiler is a bit smarter in this case,  and translates it into `b { w => { w.a(); true } } `

Comment: but `def e(): Boolean = b {_ => _.a(); true }` also will throw `<console>:16: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$3) => x$3.a())
         def e(): Boolean = b {_ => _.a(); true }` type issue. Do you think I need keep this answer? @ Archeg

Comment: The construction `_ => _.a()` is weird. I think it will translate into `x => y => y.a()`, which is not something you'd want. And in it you have type-unbound `y`, which I don't think can ever by the subject of type inference. But you anyway better keep this answer. You answer somewhat helps as well, and I found this discussion very interesting, it could be useful for somebody as well.

Comment: I was wrong, it can be type-inferenced as well: `val a: (Int => Int => Int) = _ => _ + 1`

Comment: I'm not sure it can cast more light on the issue, but `def e(): Boolean = b { _.a() == Unit }` does compile.

Comment: because there is no ambiguity for `b { _.a() == Unit }` , the compiler can infer the `_` is type of `A`, I have explained why `b { _.a(); true }` has ambiguity in the last.